# Prove/disprove about power series

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm asking for your help with proving/disproving the following:
if $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n $ converges at $x=x_1$ then $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot a_nx^{n-1} $ converges at $x=x_1$ as well.

I just learned power series so not sure how to approach this really.

Any tip will be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Consider the series 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$.
which converges for $x=-1$. What about
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 3):

If you take $x_1=1$ the problem reduces to finding $a_n$
with $\sum a_n$ convergent but $\sum na_n$ divergent.
Can you find some standard series that has this property?

Comment: Solved. Thanks.